# Cytoscape: show node/edge attributes in table when clicking on it

Tags: python, flask, cytoscape.js

I'm a beginner with cytoscape.js, as I am just rendering shallow networks in a flask App.

Currently I'm able to show node and edges attributes on hovering, but information appears in a not user-friendly dictionary. What I would like to do is to show node/edge information (let's say just edges for now) in a table, once the node/edge is clicked on.

Right now, the function creating the popper element on hovering is this:

```
function makePopper(ele) {
    let ref = ele.popperRef(); // used only for positioning
    ele.tippy = tippy(ref, {
      // tippy options:
      content: () => {
        let content = document.createElement("div");
        content.innerHTML = '<p>' + JSON.stringify(ele.data(), undefined, 2) + '</p>';
        return content;
      },
      trigger: "manual" // probably want manual mode
    });
  }
```

As you can see the innerHTML is populated with ele.data (node or edge attributes). I would like to render this in a table.

I've been searching a little, but it seems nobody has had the same need.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not limited by Popper or Cytoscape.js when it comes to what data should be included in your tooltip and how it should look, it's strictly HTML.

Working example with column names on the left at - https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/ExVLEwj

```js
/**
 *
 * @param target node or edge
 */
static bindPopper(target) {
    let tooltipId = `popper-target-${target.id()}`;

    // check if existing tooltip and remove if necessary
    let existingTarget = document.getElementById(tooltipId);
    if (existingTarget && existingTarget.length !== 0) {
        existingTarget.remove();
    }

    let popper = target.popper({
        content: () => {
            // create div container
            let tooltip = document.createElement('div');

            // adding id for easier JavaScript control
            tooltip.id = tooltipId;

            // adding class for easier CSS control
            tooltip.classList.add('target-popper');

            // create actual table
            let table = document.createElement('table');

            // append table to div container
            tooltip.append(table);
            let targetData = target.data();

            // loop through target data
            for (let prop in targetData) {
                if (!targetData.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

                let targetValue = targetData[prop];
                // no recursive or reduce support
                if (typeof targetValue === "object") continue;

                let tr = table.insertRow();

                let tdTitle = tr.insertCell();
                let tdValue = tr.insertCell();

                tdTitle.innerText = prop;
                tdValue.innerText = targetValue;
            }

            document.body.appendChild(tooltip);

            return tooltip;
        }
    });

    target.on('position', () => {
        popper.scheduleUpdate();
    });

    target.cy().on('pan zoom resize', () => {
        popper.scheduleUpdate();
    });

    target.on('mouseover', () => {
        if (document.getElementById(tooltipId)) {
            document.getElementById(tooltipId).classList.add('active');
        }
    }).on('mouseout', () => {
        if (document.getElementById(tooltipId)) {
            document.getElementById(tooltipId).classList.remove('active');
        }
    })
}
```

If you want a traditional table, you could get the `data` keys and create a row with those.

```js
let rowWithTitles = table.insertRow();
Object.keys(targetData).forEach(i => {
    rowWithTitles.insertCell().innerText = i;
})
```